# Insert Related List errors

Tags: 2013, error, related-list

So I have some Classes in one list and each time one is scheduled, it must have an Instructor (lookup to Instructors list). On the display form for Instructors, I used the "Insert Related List" button to get the sublist of Classes that the selected Instructor is teaching.

I thought it was working perfectly for awhile, but I while I was going through the Instructors, one of them had taught more than 30 Classes. As it is supposed to, it displayed the first 30, then gave an arrow button to move to the next page of results, but when I click the arrow, It changes to say that "There are no items to show in this view of the 'Classes' list", and then won't even let me navigate back to the first page.

I know that this Instructor has taught over sixty classes, so there definitely should be a second page, but I don't know why it isn't displaying them. Messing around with it a bit showed that the same thing happens if I try to resort the list or add an additional filter to it.

EDIT: So I was partially able to solve my problem by changing the number of elements per page to be a much larger number. Now all of the elements show because there is only one page. It's kind of a kludge, but at least I can see all the elements. This is still incomplete though because I can't filter or sort the view when it pops up.

Comment: Have you make any customizations to the list view?

Comment: I have, but I've also tried using the default unmodified list view